# How to change field value of Mocked object

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class that make request to a REST api and get the response. I want to do a test for this. Normally I should test it like this:

```
A a = new A("url");
a.login("username", "password");
List<String> expected = new ArrayList<>();

B b = new B(a);
expected.add("result1");
assertEqual(b.request(...), expected);
```

This won't work because I must login to the api and the result isn't always the same. So I came with this test:

```
//server that emulate the api
server.response(Response.from("response.json"));

A a = mock(A.class);
when(a.isLoggedIn()).thenReturn(true);

B b = new B(a);
```

The problem with this second test is I must set a url to a otherwise it won't work. A doesn't have getter and I can't change that. How can I solve this?

Comment: does class `A` have a `getURL()` that will be called by `B`? if so then just add `when(a.getURL()).thenReturn(a_url);`

Comment: you should add the getter method, is there a reason why you can't/won't?

Comment: Changing the value of mock object is plain wrong design wise. Mockito encourage people to think in interactions, accessing the field of a collaborator, creates a lot of coupling. If the API don't have that maybe mockito is not the right tool for this kind of test (i.e. with integration tests). If the code is legacy and you don't have ownership you have to be pretty explicit in the test about this trick (like a explaining `@Before` method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always reach out for a reflection, plenty of helpers around e.g. [ReflectionUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html)

In that case something like the following would do

```
    Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(a.getClass(), [Field name], [Field type]);
    ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
    ReflectionUtils.setField(field, a, [Field value]);
```

the class can be used standalone, so you don't have to use spring if you're not already

```
/**
 * Simple utility class for working with the reflection API and handling
 * reflection exceptions.
 *
 * <p>Only intended for internal use.
 *
 * @author Juergen Hoeller
 * @author Rob Harrop
 * @author Rod Johnson
 * @author Costin Leau
 * @author Sam Brannen
 * @author Chris Beams
 * @since 1.2.2
 */
public abstract class ReflectionUtils {

    /**
     * Pattern for detecting CGLIB-renamed methods.
     * @see #isCglibRenamedMethod
     */
    private static final Pattern CGLIB_RENAMED_METHOD_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("CGLIB\\$(.+)\\$\\d+");


    /**
     * Attempt to find a {@link Field field} on the supplied {@link Class} with the
     * supplied {@code name}. Searches all superclasses up to {@link Object}.
     * @param clazz the class to introspect
     * @param name the name of the field
     * @return the corresponding Field object, or {@code null} if not found
     */
    public static Field findField(Class<?> clazz, String name) {
        return findField(clazz, name, null);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to find a {@link Field field} on the supplied {@link Class} with the
     * supplied {@code name} and/or {@link Class type}. Searches all superclasses
     * up to {@link Object}.
     * @param clazz the class to introspect
     * @param name the name of the field (may be {@code null} if type is specified)
     * @param type the type of the field (may be {@code null} if name is specified)
     * @return the corresponding Field object, or {@code null} if not found
     */
    public static Field findField(Class<?> clazz, String name, Class<?> type) {
        Class<?> searchType = clazz;
        while (!Object.class.equals(searchType) && searchType != null) {
            Field[] fields = searchType.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : fields) {
                if ((name == null || name.equals(field.getName())) && (type == null || type.equals(field.getType()))) {
                    return field;
                }
            }
            searchType = searchType.getSuperclass();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Set the field represented by the supplied {@link Field field object} on the
     * specified {@link Object target object} to the specified {@code value}.
     * In accordance with {@link Field#set(Object, Object)} semantics, the new value
     * is automatically unwrapped if the underlying field has a primitive type.
     * <p>Thrown exceptions are handled via a call to {@link #handleReflectionException(Exception)}.
     * @param field the field to set
     * @param target the target object on which to set the field
     * @param value the value to set; may be {@code null}
     */
    public static void setField(Field field, Object target, Object value) {
        try {
            field.set(target, value);
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            handleReflectionException(ex);
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Unexpected reflection exception - " + ex.getClass().getName() + ": " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the field represented by the supplied {@link Field field object} on the
     * specified {@link Object target object}. In accordance with {@link Field#get(Object)}
     * semantics, the returned value is automatically wrapped if the underlying field
     * has a primitive type.
     * <p>Thrown exceptions are handled via a call to {@link #handleReflectionException(Exception)}.
     * @param field the field to get
     * @param target the target object from which to get the field
     * @return the field's current value
     */
    public static Object getField(Field field, Object target) {
        try {
            return field.get(target);
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            handleReflectionException(ex);
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Unexpected reflection exception - " + ex.getClass().getName() + ": " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to find a {@link Method} on the supplied class with the supplied name
     * and no parameters. Searches all superclasses up to {@code Object}.
     * <p>Returns {@code null} if no {@link Method} can be found.
     * @param clazz the class to introspect
     * @param name the name of the method
     * @return the Method object, or {@code null} if none found
     */
    public static Method findMethod(Class<?> clazz, String name) {
        return findMethod(clazz, name, new Class<?>[0]);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to find a {@link Method} on the supplied class with the supplied name
     * and parameter types. Searches all superclasses up to {@code Object}.
     * <p>Returns {@code null} if no {@link Method} can be found.
     * @param clazz the class to introspect
     * @param name the name of the method
     * @param paramTypes the parameter types of the method
     * (may be {@code null} to indicate any signature)
     * @return the Method object, or {@code null} if none found
     */
    public static Method findMethod(Class<?> clazz, String name, Class<?>... paramTypes) {
        Class<?> searchType = clazz;
        while (searchType != null) {
            Method[] methods = (searchType.isInterface() ? searchType.getMethods() : searchType.getDeclaredMethods());
            for (Method method : methods) {
                if (name.equals(method.getName()) &&
                        (paramTypes == null || Arrays.equals(paramTypes, method.getParameterTypes()))) {
                    return method;
                }
            }
            searchType = searchType.getSuperclass();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Invoke the specified {@link Method} against the supplied target object with no arguments.
     * The target object can be {@code null} when invoking a static {@link Method}.
     * <p>Thrown exceptions are handled via a call to {@link #handleReflectionException}.
     * @param method the method to invoke
     * @param target the target object to invoke the method on
     * @return the invocation result, if any
     * @see #invokeMethod(java.lang.reflect.Method, Object, Object[])
     */
    public static Object invokeMethod(Method method, Object target) {
        return invokeMethod(method, target, new Object[0]);
    }

    /**
     * Invoke the specified {@link Method} against the supplied target object with the
     * supplied arguments. The target object can be {@code null} when invoking a
     * static {@link Method}.
     * <p>Thrown exceptions are handled via a call to {@link #handleReflectionException}.
     * @param method the method to invoke
     * @param target the target object to invoke the method on
     * @param args the invocation arguments (may be {@code null})
     * @return the invocation result, if any
     */
    public static Object invokeMethod(Method method, Object target, Object... args) {
        try {
            return method.invoke(target, args);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            handleReflectionException(ex);
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Should never get here");
    }

    /**
     * Invoke the specified JDBC API {@link Method} against the supplied target
     * object with no arguments.
     * @param method the method to invoke
     * @param target the target object to invoke the method on
     * @return the invocation result, if any
     * @throws SQLException the JDBC API SQLException to rethrow (if any)
     * @see #invokeJdbcMethod(java.lang.reflect.Method, Object, Object[])
     */
    public static Object invokeJdbcMethod(Method method, Object target) throws SQLException {
        return invokeJdbcMethod(method, target, new Object[0]);
    }

    /**
     * Invoke the specified JDBC API {@link Method} against the supplied target
     * object with the supplied arguments.
     * @param method the method to invoke
     * @param target the target object to invoke the method on
     * @param args the invocation arguments (may be {@code null})
     * @return the invocation result, if any
     * @throws SQLException the JDBC API SQLException to rethrow (if any)
     * @see #invokeMethod(java.lang.reflect.Method, Object, Object[])
     */
    public static Object invokeJdbcMethod(Method method, Object target, Object... args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            return method.invoke(target, args);
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            handleReflectionException(ex);
        }
        catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
            if (ex.getTargetException() instanceof SQLException) {
                throw (SQLException) ex.getTargetException();
            }
            handleInvocationTargetException(ex);
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Should never get here");
    }

    /**
     * Handle the given reflection exception. Should only be called if no
     * checked exception is expected to be thrown by the target method.
     * <p>Throws the underlying RuntimeException or Error in case of an
     * InvocationTargetException with such a root cause. Throws an
     * IllegalStateException with an appropriate message else.
     * @param ex the reflection exception to handle
     */
    public static void handleReflectionException(Exception ex) {
        if (ex instanceof NoSuchMethodException) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Method not found: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        if (ex instanceof IllegalAccessException) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not access method: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        if (ex instanceof InvocationTargetException) {
            handleInvocationTargetException((InvocationTargetException) ex);
        }
        if (ex instanceof RuntimeException) {
            throw (RuntimeException) ex;
        }
        throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(ex);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the given invocation target exception. Should only be called if no
     * checked exception is expected to be thrown by the target method.
     * <p>Throws the underlying RuntimeException or Error in case of such a root
     * cause. Throws an IllegalStateException else.
     * @param ex the invocation target exception to handle
     */
    public static void handleInvocationTargetException(InvocationTargetException ex) {
        rethrowRuntimeException(ex.getTargetException());
    }

    /**
     * Rethrow the given {@link Throwable exception}, which is presumably the
     * <em>target exception</em> of an {@link InvocationTargetException}. Should
     * only be called if no checked exception is expected to be thrown by the
     * target method.
     * <p>Rethrows the underlying exception cast to an {@link RuntimeException} or
     * {@link Error} if appropriate; otherwise, throws an
     * {@link IllegalStateException}.
     * @param ex the exception to rethrow
     * @throws RuntimeException the rethrown exception
     */
    public static void rethrowRuntimeException(Throwable ex) {
        if (ex instanceof RuntimeException) {
            throw (RuntimeException) ex;
        }
        if (ex instanceof Error) {
            throw (Error) ex;
        }
        throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(ex);
    }

    /**
     * Rethrow the given {@link Throwable exception}, which is presumably the
     * <em>target exception</em> of an {@link InvocationTargetException}. Should
     * only be called if no checked exception is expected to be thrown by the
     * target method.
     * <p>Rethrows the underlying exception cast to an {@link Exception} or
     * {@link Error} if appropriate; otherwise, throws an
     * {@link IllegalStateException}.
     * @param ex the exception to rethrow
     * @throws Exception the rethrown exception (in case of a checked exception)
     */
    public static void rethrowException(Throwable ex) throws Exception {
        if (ex instanceof Exception) {
            throw (Exception) ex;
        }
        if (ex instanceof Error) {
            throw (Error) ex;
        }
        throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(ex);
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the given method explicitly declares the given
     * exception or one of its superclasses, which means that an exception of
     * that type can be propagated as-is within a reflective invocation.
     * @param method the declaring method
     * @param exceptionType the exception to throw
     * @return {@code true} if the exception can be thrown as-is;
     * {@code false} if it needs to be wrapped
     */
    public static boolean declaresException(Method method, Class<?> exceptionType) {
        Class<?>[] declaredExceptions = method.getExceptionTypes();
        for (Class<?> declaredException : declaredExceptions) {
            if (declaredException.isAssignableFrom(exceptionType)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the given field is a "public static final" constant.
     * @param field the field to check
     */
    public static boolean isPublicStaticFinal(Field field) {
        int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
        return (Modifier.isPublic(modifiers) && Modifier.isStatic(modifiers) && Modifier.isFinal(modifiers));
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the given method is an "equals" method.
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(Object)
     */
    public static boolean isEqualsMethod(Method method) {
        if (method == null || !method.getName().equals("equals")) {
            return false;
        }
        Class<?>[] paramTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
        return (paramTypes.length == 1 && paramTypes[0] == Object.class);
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the given method is a "hashCode" method.
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    public static boolean isHashCodeMethod(Method method) {
        return (method != null && method.getName().equals("hashCode") && method.getParameterTypes().length == 0);
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the given method is a "toString" method.
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    public static boolean isToStringMethod(Method method) {
        return (method != null && method.getName().equals("toString") && method.getParameterTypes().length == 0);
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the given method is originally declared by {@link java.lang.Object}.
     */
    public static boolean isObjectMethod(Method method) {
        if (method == null) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            Object.class.getDeclaredMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the given method is a CGLIB 'renamed' method,
     * following the pattern "CGLIB$methodName$0".
     * @param renamedMethod the method to check
     * @see org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer#rename
     */
    public static boolean isCglibRenamedMethod(Method renamedMethod) {
        return CGLIB_RENAMED_METHOD_PATTERN.matcher(renamedMethod.getName()).matches();
    }

    /**
     * Make the given field accessible, explicitly setting it accessible if
     * necessary. The {@code setAccessible(true)} method is only called
     * when actually necessary, to avoid unnecessary conflicts with a JVM
     * SecurityManager (if active).
     * @param field the field to make accessible
     * @see java.lang.reflect.Field#setAccessible
     */
    public static void makeAccessible(Field field) {
        if ((!Modifier.isPublic(field.getModifiers()) || !Modifier.isPublic(field.getDeclaringClass().getModifiers()) ||
                Modifier.isFinal(field.getModifiers())) && !field.isAccessible()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make the given method accessible, explicitly setting it accessible if
     * necessary. The {@code setAccessible(true)} method is only called
     * when actually necessary, to avoid unnecessary conflicts with a JVM
     * SecurityManager (if active).
     * @param method the method to make accessible
     * @see java.lang.reflect.Method#setAccessible
     */
    public static void makeAccessible(Method method) {
        if ((!Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers()) || !Modifier.isPublic(method.getDeclaringClass().getModifiers()))
                && !method.isAccessible()) {
            method.setAccessible(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make the given constructor accessible, explicitly setting it accessible
     * if necessary. The {@code setAccessible(true)} method is only called
     * when actually necessary, to avoid unnecessary conflicts with a JVM
     * SecurityManager (if active).
     * @param ctor the constructor to make accessible
     * @see java.lang.reflect.Constructor#setAccessible
     */
    public static void makeAccessible(Constructor<?> ctor) {
        if ((!Modifier.isPublic(ctor.getModifiers()) || !Modifier.isPublic(ctor.getDeclaringClass().getModifiers()))
                && !ctor.isAccessible()) {
            ctor.setAccessible(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Perform the given callback operation on all matching methods of the given
     * class and superclasses.
     * <p>The same named method occurring on subclass and superclass will appear
     * twice, unless excluded by a {@link MethodFilter}.
     * @param clazz class to start looking at
     * @param mc the callback to invoke for each method
     * @see #doWithMethods(Class, MethodCallback, MethodFilter)
     */
    public static void doWithMethods(Class<?> clazz, MethodCallback mc) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        doWithMethods(clazz, mc, null);
    }

    /**
     * Perform the given callback operation on all matching methods of the given
     * class and superclasses (or given interface and super-interfaces).
     * <p>The same named method occurring on subclass and superclass will appear
     * twice, unless excluded by the specified {@link MethodFilter}.
     * @param clazz class to start looking at
     * @param mc the callback to invoke for each method
     * @param mf the filter that determines the methods to apply the callback to
     */
    public static void doWithMethods(Class<?> clazz, MethodCallback mc, MethodFilter mf)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {

        // Keep backing up the inheritance hierarchy.
        Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (mf != null && !mf.matches(method)) {
                continue;
            }
            try {
                mc.doWith(method);
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Shouldn't be illegal to access method '" + method.getName()
                        + "': " + ex);
            }
        }
        if (clazz.getSuperclass() != null) {
            doWithMethods(clazz.getSuperclass(), mc, mf);
        }
        else if (clazz.isInterface()) {
            for (Class<?> superIfc : clazz.getInterfaces()) {
                doWithMethods(superIfc, mc, mf);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get all declared methods on the leaf class and all superclasses. Leaf
     * class methods are included first.
     */
    public static Method[] getAllDeclaredMethods(Class<?> leafClass) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        final List<Method> methods = new ArrayList<Method>(32);
        doWithMethods(leafClass, new MethodCallback() {
            public void doWith(Method method) {
                methods.add(method);
            }
        });
        return methods.toArray(new Method[methods.size()]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the unique set of declared methods on the leaf class and all superclasses. Leaf
     * class methods are included first and while traversing the superclass hierarchy any methods found
     * with signatures matching a method already included are filtered out.
     */
    public static Method[] getUniqueDeclaredMethods(Class<?> leafClass) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        final List<Method> methods = new ArrayList<Method>(32);
        doWithMethods(leafClass, new MethodCallback() {
            public void doWith(Method method) {
                boolean knownSignature = false;
                Method methodBeingOverriddenWithCovariantReturnType = null;
                for (Method existingMethod : methods) {
                    if (method.getName().equals(existingMethod.getName()) &&
                            Arrays.equals(method.getParameterTypes(), existingMethod.getParameterTypes())) {
                        // Is this a covariant return type situation?
                        if (existingMethod.getReturnType() != method.getReturnType() &&
                                existingMethod.getReturnType().isAssignableFrom(method.getReturnType())) {
                            methodBeingOverriddenWithCovariantReturnType = existingMethod;
                        }
                        else {
                            knownSignature = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (methodBeingOverriddenWithCovariantReturnType != null) {
                    methods.remove(methodBeingOverriddenWithCovariantReturnType);
                }
                if (!knownSignature && !isCglibRenamedMethod(method)) {
                    methods.add(method);
                }
            }
        });
        return methods.toArray(new Method[methods.size()]);
    }

    /**
     * Invoke the given callback on all fields in the target class, going up the
     * class hierarchy to get all declared fields.
     * @param clazz the target class to analyze
     * @param fc the callback to invoke for each field
     */
    public static void doWithFields(Class<?> clazz, FieldCallback fc) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        doWithFields(clazz, fc, null);
    }

    /**
     * Invoke the given callback on all fields in the target class, going up the
     * class hierarchy to get all declared fields.
     * @param clazz the target class to analyze
     * @param fc the callback to invoke for each field
     * @param ff the filter that determines the fields to apply the callback to
     */
    public static void doWithFields(Class<?> clazz, FieldCallback fc, FieldFilter ff)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {

        // Keep backing up the inheritance hierarchy.
        Class<?> targetClass = clazz;
        do {
            Field[] fields = targetClass.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : fields) {
                // Skip static and final fields.
                if (ff != null && !ff.matches(field)) {
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    fc.doWith(field);
                }
                catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(
                            "Shouldn't be illegal to access field '" + field.getName() + "': " + ex);
                }
            }
            targetClass = targetClass.getSuperclass();
        }
        while (targetClass != null && targetClass != Object.class);
    }

    /**
     * Given the source object and the destination, which must be the same class
     * or a subclass, copy all fields, including inherited fields. Designed to
     * work on objects with public no-arg constructors.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the arguments are incompatible
     */
    public static void shallowCopyFieldState(final Object src, final Object dest) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (src == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Source for field copy cannot be null");
        }
        if (dest == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Destination for field copy cannot be null");
        }
        if (!src.getClass().isAssignableFrom(dest.getClass())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Destination class [" + dest.getClass().getName()
                    + "] must be same or subclass as source class [" + src.getClass().getName() + "]");
        }
        doWithFields(src.getClass(), new FieldCallback() {
            public void doWith(Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
                makeAccessible(field);
                Object srcValue = field.get(src);
                field.set(dest, srcValue);
            }
        }, COPYABLE_FIELDS);
    }


    /**
     * Action to take on each method.
     */
    public interface MethodCallback {

        /**
         * Perform an operation using the given method.
         * @param method the method to operate on
         */
        void doWith(Method method) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException;
    }


    /**
     * Callback optionally used to filter methods to be operated on by a method callback.
     */
    public interface MethodFilter {

        /**
         * Determine whether the given method matches.
         * @param method the method to check
         */
        boolean matches(Method method);
    }


    /**
     * Callback interface invoked on each field in the hierarchy.
     */
    public interface FieldCallback {

        /**
         * Perform an operation using the given field.
         * @param field the field to operate on
         */
        void doWith(Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException;
    }


    /**
     * Callback optionally used to filter fields to be operated on by a field callback.
     */
    public interface FieldFilter {

        /**
         * Determine whether the given field matches.
         * @param field the field to check
         */
        boolean matches(Field field);
    }


    /**
     * Pre-built FieldFilter that matches all non-static, non-final fields.
     */
    public static FieldFilter COPYABLE_FIELDS = new FieldFilter() {

        public boolean matches(Field field) {
            return !(Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()) || Modifier.isFinal(field.getModifiers()));
        }
    };


    /**
     * Pre-built MethodFilter that matches all non-bridge methods.
     */
    public static MethodFilter NON_BRIDGED_METHODS = new MethodFilter() {

        public boolean matches(Method method) {
            return !method.isBridge();
        }
    };


    /**
     * Pre-built MethodFilter that matches all non-bridge methods
     * which are not declared on {@code java.lang.Object}.
     */
    public static MethodFilter USER_DECLARED_METHODS = new MethodFilter() {

        public boolean matches(Method method) {
            return (!method.isBridge() && method.getDeclaringClass() != Object.class);
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: This may not be a good approach if in the future when you (or especially someone else) had to do some re-factoring.

Comment: true, very aware of this, but all approaches have its downside, its like a dilemma of testing private methods http://java.dzone.com/articles/unit-testing-private-methods, its about knowing the downsides and making an informative decision

Comment: agree, all approaches have their own limitations.

Comment: You say that the class is standalone so how I can use it without alone without I download Soring. Can you explain that or tell where to look for an answer please?

Comment: you can find it online, but I've pasted it in the answer anyways

Answer (score 0):

You should provide access to the url in class `A` with a method like `getURL()`. Then use this method from `B`. 
When mocking `A` just add `when(a.getURL()).thenReturn(a_url);`.